# Find declaration of a global variable in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables, variable-declaration

### Is there a quick and concise way of finding the declaration of a global variable in PHP?

If we are dealing with a large codebase where the global variable may be referenced in many different files:

- Using `ctags` to jump to declaration takes you to the local statement where the global is brought into scope in the current file
- Searching for `global $foo` using `grep` or `ack` results in a list of files where the global was brought into scope, but not the exact declaration of the global variable

Is there any tool/vim plugin/etc that will tell you exactly where the global is being declared for the first time?

---

**Update:** I guess you could set a watch breakpoint and look for the first access to the variable. Unfortunately, this type of breakpoint is not yet supported in Xdebug, so for my particular setup, it wouldn't work.

Comment: If you have a modern IDE ctrl+click on the variable (or your hotkey of choice). Otherwise, search for `$var =` (will also match local scope with the same name)

Comment: Using vim, so I guess that's one place where an IDE would do better. But surely if it's possible in an IDE, there's a vim plugin that does the same?

Comment: I'm sure emacs can ;) (that's a joke)

Answer (score 3):

Are you a Unix-based OS?

I usually do something like `grep -rn 'global $myvar' .`

in the top-level directory.  This does a recursive search of files in the current directory for the declaration.

Or, if you want to get fancy you can search for only PHP files:

`grep -rn --include '*.php' 'global $myvar' .`

Comment: This is exactly what I do with [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) (which is recursive and searches only code files by default). This still nets me several dozen lines from different files, though.

Comment: Hmm *maybe* the assignment is near the `global $myvar`?  If so, you could search a few lines below for the assignment?  `grep -rn -A 3 --include '*.php' 'global $myvar' . | grep = ` (you could use an OR instead of two `grep`s too).  

Maybe paste some of your output to see what sort of data you're getting?

Comment: I mainly wanted to know if there was a concise way to find the declaration of a global variable, akin to what Frits van Campen mentioned about IDEs in his comment. I've edited my question to reflect that. Currently, I use the same methods you outline - but it can involve looking through several files until you find the one where the variable is declared.

Comment: What if I use windows and have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't need to be any declaration beyond the `global $foo` declarations you are finding.  These do declare the global variable.  It can easily be the case that the global variable is only referenced from within these functions.

The following code works, for example:

```
function print_it() {
    global $my_global;
    echo $my_global;
}
function set_it() {
    global $my_global;
    $my_global = 17;
}
set_it();
print_it();  // echos 17
```