# Find the declaration of any variable in php file in a PHP project

Tags: php, ide

This question is different from: [Find declaration of a global variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061788/find-declaration-of-a-global-variable-in-php)  as that question is asked specifically for Linux as the questioner has mentioned the use of grep, etc.

Actually, I want to contribute to phpMyAdmin. The code has many Global variables and I want to find where they were declared. I am using Windows.

Comment: Install something like Cygwin and use grep. Last I checked, there really wasn't a good windows command to do it.

Comment: You can get grep for windows. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Comment: Or Notepad++ has a regexp "find in files" ... actually, thinking about it, I cobbled one up in Perl once aeons ago.

Comment: Please also mention the reason for downvote whoever it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an IDE? If so you could always do a project wide search for the specific variable.

Otherwise text editors like Notepad++ have a "Open folder as workspace" option. 
Doing this then running a search should help.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't need to be any declaration in the global scope.
The `global $foo` declarations that you see in the functions where $foo is used are sufficient.
It can easily be the case that the global variable is only referenced from within these functions.

The following code works, for example:

```
function print_it() {
    global $my_global;
    echo $my_global;
}
function set_it() {
    global $my_global;
    $my_global = 17;
}
set_it();
print_it();  // echos 17
```